# My css style background-color in a specific situation does not work

Tags: html, css

I've coded this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <style>
            .menu-div {
                position: absolute;
                top:200px;
                width:100px;
                height:20px;
                background-color: #CBDA90;
                z-index:10000;
            }
            .menu-div:hover { // Menu div css style
                background-color: white;
            }
            .second-position-container {
                position:fixed;
                width:100%;
                height:2400px;
            }
            .position-container {
                width:1333px;
                height:800px;
                position: relative;
                margin-left :auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            .container {
                position: relative;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width:1333px;
                height:800px;
            }
            .side-panel {  
                position: absolute;
                top:120px;
                width: 240px;
                height:300px;
                margin-top: 5px;
                border:4px solid #6C7532;
            }
        
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="menu-div"></div>
            <div class="second-position-container">
                <div class="position-container">
                    <div class="side-panel">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container" id="container-search">
            </div>
            <div id="container-sim" class="container">
                <div class="tools">
                </div>
                <div id="image-block" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container" id="container-forum"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And my `.menu-div:hover` style does not work if it is append to the side panel div.I was trying to make, like a menu where when you hover your mouse over the same menu it changes the background color.

But if I append it to the body it works fine.

Comment: You're going to have to expand on what you mean when you say "my .menu-div:hover style does not work if it is append to the side panel div".

Comment: when I hover my mouse over the dive it does not change its background color

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your comment out // Menu div CSS style. In CSS use /* */ to comment out not // .. Try to learn how to comment out in CSS.

Comment: Did you mean `/*...*/`? Putting comments between 2 front slashes isn't valid.

Comment: i'm sorry that comment is not on my original code